# Component Exception in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, multipleselection

I use this library for multiple selection

> https://openbase.io/js/react-native-multiple-select

And I just copy their code, its just copy-paste code and should works?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select';

const items = [{
    id: '92iijs7yta',
    name: 'Ondo'
  }, {
    id: 'a0s0a8ssbsd',
    name: 'Ogun'
  }, {
    id: '16hbajsabsd',
    name: 'Calabar'
  }, {
    id: 'nahs75a5sg',
    name: 'Lagos'
  }, {
    id: '667atsas',
    name: 'Maiduguri'
  }, {
    id: 'hsyasajs',
    name: 'Anambra'
  }, {
    id: 'djsjudksjd',
    name: 'Benue'
  }, {
    id: 'sdhyaysdj',
    name: 'Kaduna'
  }, {
    id: 'suudydjsjd',
    name: 'Abuja'
    }
];

class MultiSelectExample extends Component {

  state = {
    selectedItems : []
  }; 

  
  onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MultiSelect
          hideTags
          items={items}
          uniqueKey="id"
          ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={selectedItems}
          selectText="Pick Items"
          searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
          onChangeInput={ (text)=> console.log(text)}
          altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
          tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
          tagBorderColor="#CCC"
          tagTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
          selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
          itemTextColor="#000"
          displayKey="name"
          searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
          submitButtonColor="#CCC"
          submitButtonText="Submit"
        />
        <View>
          {this.multiSelect.getSelectedItemsExt(selectedItems)}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I got error Component Exception, can someone help me how to fix this or give me some other library? Because code its simple I don't know how can not works?

Answer (score 0):

Change `ref` name from `component` to something else like `multiSelectRef`

```
ref={(multiSelectRef) => { this.multiSelect = multiSelectRef}}
```

Comment: Can you help me with this problem? I will really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed react-native-vector-icons in your project before using this package. If you have not done so, then go to the given link to install-https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Do you have some other solution?